# Is it possible, in Visual Studio Code, to directly select the text inside a fold (code inside a method)?

Tags: function, visual-studio-code, copy, selection

I've seen that in vim, one can directly select the code belonging a function.

For example, assuming this Python function:

```py
def my_function():
  foo()
  bar()
  baz()
```

with the cursor inside it, by using a certain command, on can select the three lines `foo()` to `baz()`.

In VSC, I can emulate this functionality by:

- execute the "go to parent fold" command
- execute the "fold" command
- select the folded selection (three dots)
- copy selection
- execute the "unfold" command

This is very tedious, though. Is there any way to perform this functionality in a direct way?

Comment: If selected function definition "def my_function():" is not a problem for you, you can use "Expand Selection" command. When cursor is inside a function you can run "Expand Selection" until you get whole function selected.

Comment: I think that it doesn't work as intended, unfortunately. I've tried it on a method definition inside a class, and after executing `Expand Selection` in a line inside the method, it selected the whole class.

Comment: I've got version 1.63.1 of VSCode.
`Expand Selection` for a class in Python works as follows (assuming the cursor is in a method at self.ty>>|<<pe):
word "type" around cursor -> "self.type" -> "self.type = type" -> "self.type = type" with indentation -> whole method with "def name(args):" -> whole method with "def name(args):" with indentation -> whole class"

Comment: I've just noticed that in C++ `Expand Selection` works in a different way - one step in `Expand Selection` combo selects only a method body, i.e. code between brackets of a method - This is what you want, but for Python, isn't it? For Python command `Expand Selection` works somehow different...